# Issue with Next.js page rendering wrong data when navigating quickly between pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, axios

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with data rendering on a Next.js page in my application. Here's the scenario: I have a Next.js page that displays customer information based on a query parameter `cid`. The page fetches the customer data and related groups data from an API using Axios, and then renders this data on the page.

The problem arises when I rapidly navigate between different customer IDs, i.e. `cid`=1, `cid`=2, etc. Sometimes, when I quickly switch between pages, the page renders data for the wrong `cid`. For example, when I navigate from `cid`=2 to `cid`=1, the page might still render data for `cid`=2 instead of `cid`=1.

I've tried to debug this issue by ensuring that the `fetchData` function executes in the correct order and by using the latest value of `router.query.cid`. However, the problem persists.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import { config } from '@/lib/headerConfig';
import axios from 'axios';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// auth
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

// components
const CustomersLayout = dynamic(() => import('@/components/customer/layout/Index'));
const Spinner = dynamic(() => import('@/components/global/Spinner'));

// zustand
import { useCustomersStore } from '@/middleware/zustand/customers';

const CustomerInformationPage = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { customers, setCustomers, setPreviousPage } = useCustomersStore();
    const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({});
    const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCustomers(props.customers);
        setPreviousPage(props.previousPage);
    }, [props.customers, props.previousPage]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                if (router.query.cid) {
                    const customerData = await fetchCustomer(router.query.cid);
                    const groupsData = await fetchGroups(router.query.cid);
                    setCustomer(customerData);
                    setGroups(groupsData);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching customer or groups:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [router.query.cid]);

    const fetchCustomer = async (cid) => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const { signal } = controller;
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`/api/customer?cid=${cid}`, { signal, ...config });
            return res.data[0];
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        } finally {
            controller.abort();
        }
    };

    const fetchGroups = async (cid) => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const { signal } = controller;
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`/api/customer/groups?cid=${cid}`, { signal, ...config });
            return res.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        } finally {
            controller.abort();
        }
    };

    if (customers.length < 1) {
        return <Spinner />;
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Customer Information</title>
            </Head>

            <CustomersLayout>
                {console.log({
                    customerID: customer.CustomerID,
                    routerQueryCid: router.query.cid,
                })}
                <>
                    <p>
                        {customer && customer.CompanyName}
                        <br />

                        {groups.length > 0 && groups[0].ProjectGroupName}
                    </p>
                </>
            </CustomersLayout>
        </>
    );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const session = await getSession(ctx);
    const { company_name } = ctx.query;

    const headers = ctx.req.headers;
    try {
        if (session && session.user.Permissions['Customer-Customer Information'].PermissionLevel > 1) {
            const customers = (
                await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/customers`, {
                    headers: {
                        Cookie: headers.cookie,
                        authorization: process.env.HEADER,
                    },
                })
            ).data;
            const previousPage = ctx.req.headers.referer || '';
            return {
                props: {
                    customers,
                    previousPage,
                },
            };
        } else if (session && session.user.Permissions['Customer-Customer Information'].PermissionLevel < 2) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: `/${company_name}/error/403`,
                    permanent: false,
                },
            };
        } else {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: `/login?next=${ctx.req.url}`,
                    permanent: false,
                },
            };
        }
    } catch {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: `/${company_name}/error/403`,
                permanent: false,
            },
        };
    }
};

export default CustomerInformationPage;
```

I suspect that this issue might be related to asynchronous data fetching and state management, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Could anyone provide insights into why this issue might be occurring and suggest potential solutions to ensure that the correct data is rendered for each cid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest implementing the abort controllers in such a way that allows you to also cancel in-flight requests when the component unmounts or is otherwise re-running the effect with the new id value.

Example:

```
const CustomerInformationPage = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { customers, setCustomers, setPreviousPage } = useCustomersStore();

  const [customer, setCustomer] = useState({});
  const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setCustomers(props.customers);
    setPreviousPage(props.previousPage);
  }, [props.customers, props.previousPage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;

    const fetchCustomer = async (cid) => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `/api/customer?cid=${cid}`,
          { signal, ...config }
        );
        return data[0];
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
      }
    };

    const fetchGroups = async (cid) => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `/api/customer/groups?cid=${cid}`,
          { signal, ...config }
        );
        return data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
      }
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (!router.query.cid) {
       return;
      }

      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const [customerData, groupsData] = await Promise.all([
          fetchCustomer(router.query.cid),
          fetchGroups(router.query.cid)
        ]);
        setCustomer(customerData);
        setGroups(groupsData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching customer or groups:', error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [router.query.cid]);

  if (isLoading || !customers.length) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Customer Information</title>
      </Head>

      <CustomersLayout>
        <p>
          {customer?.CompanyName}
          <br />

          {groups[0]?.ProjectGroupName}
        </p>
      </CustomersLayout>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've implemented abort controllers in my code as you advised, and it works perfectly. Now, I can cancel in-flight requests when the component unmounts or when it's re-running the effect with the new id value.